# MySql SP - Data too long error

Tags: mysql, long-integer

I have created a SP in MySql, where an input parameter have longText type.

I want to pass 12,000 characters into that sp. But it gives me an error - "Data too long for column 'inputParam' at row 1".

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

```
drop procedure if exists foo;
delimiter #

create procedure foo(in p_string longtext)
begin
select length(p_string) as len;
end#

delimiter ;

set @s = '5,14,16,20,34,38,39,41,45,53,59,61,63,....');

call foo(@s);

+-------+
| len   |
+-------+
| 14479 |
+-------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

see http://pastie.org/1685774 for full script !

Answer (score 0):

Well the TEXT type for mysql can contain a maximum length of 4,294,967,295 chars. So passing in 12,000 chars into a type LONGTEXT should definitely work. There must be something else wrong with your statement. Could You please post your SP and the call you are making to it?